# Send a batch file to a Windows machine, and execute it

Tags: windows, remote, batch, pstools

I know PsExec is perfect for sending files over a computer on a network and then execute it on that remote computer, however I can't use PsExec because I'm developing a piece of software and I can't have PsExec as a dependency (for legal reasons etc.).

What's the easiest way to achieve the execution part on a remote computer? Is it really that hard? I am already copying the .bat file with xcopy... I just need to run it.

Comment: have a look at WMI or DCOM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute a script, or binary, remotely using WMI.  This is a minimal example, written in VBS, which runs the batch file `C:\test.cmd` located on the remote computer *FCSD-ISC1*.

```
strComputer = "FCSD-ISC1"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
objWMIService.Create "C:\test.cmd", null, null, intProcessID
```

This is covered in more detail in [this Scripting Guy article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/12/08/how-can-i-start-a-process-and-then-wait-for-the-process-to-end-before-terminating-the-script.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend mounting the C$ share, testing for the .\Temp directory (creating if it doesn't exist), and copying there.  (There is an "admin$" administrative share, but I recommend against using it.)

You can do this from the command line via `net use * \\servername\c$ /user:domain/account`
or specify a drive as `net use t: \\servername\c$ /user:domain/account`

This should be well documented in MSDN.  If writing for a script, there are a lot of examples in the Microsoft Script Center Repository

Comment: Even if you mount the remote share, execution of the batch file would occur on the local computer.  @Luca says he's using `xcopy` place the file on the remote machine.

Comment: Yup, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I know is not relevant anymore but for the sake of completness(this page is high on google) i'll add here RemCom, which is an open source version of Psexec
get it here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/rce/